# How to store values from an observable in a a variable or property

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have been working on a project using angular and firebase / firestore.

I have the below code:

```
this.cadet = this.cadetCollection.valueChanges().subscribe(x => {
  this.cadetName = x[0].Cadet;
  this.cadetCompany = x[0].Company;
  this.cadetId = x[0].CadetId;
  return x as Cadets[];
}));
```

I am able to log the data to the console, as well as use the data via interpolation within my html template. However what I really need to do is to store the data within a component property or a variable so that i can use some of the data for calculations.

I'm still pretty new to angular and observables so please be kind :)

After some comments i've attempted the following:

```
    this.cadets = this.cadetCollection.valueChanges().subscribe(x => {
  this.cadetName = x[0].Cadet;
  this.cadetCompany = x[0].Company;
  this.cadetId = x[0].CadetId;
  this.cadet = x[0];
  console.log(this.cadet);
  return x as Cadets[];
});

console.log('Cadet is ' + this.cadet);
```

It seems that the object is returned to the console whenever it is within the subscribe method but is undefined after that.

Comment: Do you want to store only one cadet or all cadets?

Comment: Just one, the cadetCollection is a query with a limit of one document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However what I really need to do is to store the data within a
>   component property or a variable so that I can use some of the data
>   for calculations.?

You are working with [async programming](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript) you cannot pause the execution of the code and your subscription will be resolved in future but you cannot predict when. what you can do is You can store the value in a class property and invoke a method inside subscribe which ensures the method is only invoked when your cadet object is populated not before that.Refer [this](https://developer.telerik.com/topics/web-development/introduction-observables-angular-developers/) for better understanding.

```
public cadet=[];
this.cadet = this.cadetCollection.valueChanges().subscribe(x => {
 this.cadet=x;
this.myMethod(this.cadet);//your logic
}));
```

Comment: Yes - based on content of question - it looks like OP is not well aware of Observables - in your answer you have used phrase "async functions" without describing what you mean by them.  And, in addition you have introduced `myMethod` in your answer without explaining what it is and why is it needed.   I feel this answer is similar to Kevin's answer - so I have downvoted it as it is not giving any assistance to OP.

Comment: @WandMaker I have updated my answer with relevant changes

Comment: @user1836162 Mark it if it helped you

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have a `cadet` property in the same component, you can just assign `x[0]` to `this.cadet`:

```
this.cadetCollection.valueChanges().subscribe(x => {
  this.cadet = x[0];
}));
```

**Updates after new info provided:**

> It seems that the object is returned to the console whenever it is within the subscribe method but is undefined after that.

Not quite - code in the subscribe block runs asynchronously so buy the time `console.log('Cadet is ' + this.cadet);` runs, the subscribe block has not been executed yet!

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Resolver : https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve
   The resolver will change the state after the request is done.
2. async-await : 
   Observable and Promise are asynchronous and that's why your variables in subscribe method are undefined. Using async-await you will be able to fetch the data from subscribe in your local variables.

```js
        async myMethod(){
          this.cadet = await this.cadetCollection.valueChanges().subscribe(x => {
          this.cadetName = x[0].Cadet;
          this.cadetCompany = x[0].Company;
          this.cadetId = x[0].CadetId;
          return x as Cadets[];
        }));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a user that posted this answer earlier however i'm not seeing it any more.

What i was able to do is create a method that set the value within a property, and then call that method within the subscribe method on the observable.

```
  this.cadets = this.cadetCollection.valueChanges().subscribe(x => {
  this.cadetName = x[0].Cadet;
  this.cadetCompany = x[0].Company;
  this.cadetId = x[0].CadetId;
  this.cadet = x[0];
  this.setCurrentCadet(x[0]);
  console.log(this.cadet);
  return x as Cadets[];
});
```

Thanks to everyone who commented and helped me with this!

Answer (score -1):

You can simply do this as kevin suggested:

`public cadet = {}
this.cadetCollection.valueChanges().subscribe(x => this.cadet = x ));`

For further operations on cadet, all you have to do is check whether cadet is defined before doing any calculations.

Comment: I think this answer is same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/50013603/794242 - but lacks any kind of explanation